# Convert string array to array in validation pipe nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I get the following item back from my api controller call using this query [http://you.host/api/v1/all?lookup=["s1","s2"]](http://you.host/api/v1/all?lookup=%5B%22s1%22,%22s2%22%5D) :

```
{ lookup: '["s1", "s2"]' }
```

Class validator and transformer

```
export class Filter {
  @Type(() => String)
  @IsArray()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  lookup?: string[];
}
```

Controller

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  @Get('all')
  async getAll(@Query() data: Filter): Promise<string[]> {
    console.log(data)
    return data
  }
```

I want

```
{ lookup: ["s1", "s2"] }
```

In my JavaScript I tried services = JSON.parse(data) - didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the returned data. `lookup` is actually returned as a string.

```
{ lookup: '["s1", "s2"]' }
```

Either fix the api to send an array of strings or try this

```
const data = { lookup: '["s1", "s2"]' }
const parsedData = {
    lookup: JSON.parse(data.lookup)
}
```